# Move upload file field automatically after editing its container node

Tags: files

Suppose you have 'Book' content type with three fields: 
- class (content taxonomy field)
- category (content taxnonomy field)
- book file ( file upload)

the filefield path settings for 'book file' : 
class/category

so when changing one of them, the file directory should be changed automatically ( without re upload it again).

Any suggestions?